# Will the Unity "file manager" feature right-clicks?

Tags: unity, nautilus

One thing that disturbs my workflow with Unity is that I can not right-click on items in the "file browsing mode".

For example, if I want to open a photo not with EOG but with Shotwell Editor, I first of to open the file by left-clicking on it, and then select "Edit with ...". Simply right-clicking on it would be much easier.

The menu could be implement to look similar to those when you right-click on a launcher icon. **Are there any plans to implement such a functionality?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, it will. I'm not sure if it's going to happen for 11.04, but 11.10 wil see a lot of work on the dash and places. For 11.04 we're going to bring nautilus back into the front so that working with files is easier until we flesh out the interaction details for the dash.

Comment: Do you have evidence for this in the form of a link? Or are you a Unity developer yourself?

Comment: Yes he's a unity developer, perhaps a mention of that in your bio field @Alex?

Comment: Alex, any plans for 12.04?

Comment: Or maybe 12.10?

Comment: See comment #8 for another source of this -> https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-lens-files/+bug/667323